# Logo in beamer on the first page - how to add 2 logos on the same position

Tags: beamer, positioning, logos

I used the following code to introduce to logo in my document:

```
\titlegraphic{\includegraphics[width=2.5cm]{lit}\hspace*{5cm}~%
   \includegraphics[width=3.5cm]{uvt2}
}
```

how should i proceed such that the two logos to be on the first slide at the same position. 
Now I obtained the following picture:

[image]

Comment: "Same position"? Do you mean they should be vertically aligned? Surely "same position" doesn't mean over top of one another, correct?

Comment: yes, vertically aligned.